# How send value from controller to web page or get value from controller on web page in Spring boot?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I have Controller with method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView generate() {
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
     Thread.sleep(5000);
   //sent i value to web page. HOW???
  }
}
```

and web page

```
<html>
   <body>
    <p>value</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want on each iterate in loop sent i value to web page.

start method in controller
on web page:

```
delay 5 sec
value = 1
delay 5 sec
value = 2
....
delay 5 sec
value = 100
```

Or another way:

JS method on web page monitors the changes in the controller every 5 seconds, the controller and asks status. And update the value on web page. But I do not know how to implement it. And I do not know how to implement the first option. Help please understand how I do it.

Comment: One way that you can do is in your webpage you do a loop at your javascript code to do requests every 5 seconds, but I guess the best way to you do what you're expecting is using sockets. Socket provide a way to "talk" without the need to do extra requests.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Websockets, making a connection to your controller method.

[WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)